# How to disable Cypress time machine?

Tags: cypress

I think the hover action over a Cypress log entry (aka time machine) is nice, but in my case, it causes an uncontrollable amount of unnecessary remote requests, most of the time not needed nor requested by me. I just pass over these entries by mistake. Can I disable that feature?
[image]